# by big boat/by big boats/by a big boat

Tags: expressions

To talk about the transport we use to get to a place, we use 'by + transport', with no article needed and no change in the noun form, e.g. *by boat*.

What about in the case when we use an adjective to describe the transport?
Should we say:

1. *I went to the island **by big boat***.,
2. *I went to the island **by big boats***. or
3. *I went to the island **by a big boat***.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really "by + transport" - it's actually "by + **mode of transport**".  When you put an adjective in front of **boat**, you're no longer talking about an abstract mode of transport, and using **by** doesn't sound natural any more. "I went to the island **on a big boat**."

Comment: Do you know the word "ship"?

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way of saying it would be to use "on" (or in, depending on the vehicle in question) rather than "by", and to use the article. So "on a big boat" or, perhaps, "on the big boat", if there's only one big boat that could have been used.

That's because "by boat" isn't referring to a physical boat, but the concept of travelling on a boat, or the idea of "boat" as a method of transport. "On a boat" refers to an actual physical boat. The concept of travelling by boat can't be big, but an actual boat can be.